# Download Google Map tiles, images

Tags: maps, google, download, copyright

I would like to use the google maps downloader to save satellite images from google maps (http://www.allallsoft.com/gmd/index.html), but is it legal to use?

In the terms of service you can read that: "Unless you have received prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of particular Content), you must not: (a) copy, translate, modify, or make derivative works of the Content or any part thereof; (b) redistribute, sublicense, rent, publish, sell, assign, lease, market, transfer, or otherwise make the Products or Content available to third parties...(d) use the Products in a manner that gives you or any other person access to **mass downloads or bulk feeds of any Content**, including but not limited to numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, and visible map data..."

This program downloads the tiles and match them. The internet explorer does the same. When I view google maps in internet explorer, it downloads the tiles to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files" and put them together. So it copies imagery to folder and mass downloads them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about breaking terms an conditions of a major corporation to gain access to copy protected material.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html

> Restrictions on Use. Unless you HAVE RECEIVED Prior written authorization from Google (or, as applicable, from the provider of
>   Particular Content), **you must not: (a) copy, translate, modify, or
>   make derivative works of the Content or any portion thereof, (b )
>   redistribute, sublicense, rent, publish, sell, assign, lease, market,
>   transfer, or Otherwise make the Products or Content available to third
>   parties, (c) reverse engineer, decompile or Otherwise attempt to
>   extract the source code of the Service or** any portion thereof, Unless
>   this is Expressly permitted or required by applicable law, (d) use the
>   Products in a Manner That Gives you or any other person access to mass
>   downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, Including but not limited to
>   numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, and visible map
>   data, (e) delete, obscure, or alter in any Manner That any warning or
>   link appears in the Products or the Content, or (f) use the Service or
>   Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in
>   connection with (i) real time navigation or route guidance, Including
>   but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance That is synchronized to
>   the position of a user's sensor-enabled device, or (ii) any systems or
>   functions for automatic or autonomous control of vehicle behavior, (g)
>   use the Products to create a database of places or other local
>   listings information.

Comment: So, Is this software illegal?  http://www.allallsoft.com/gmd/index.html

Comment: Can I use screen capture to capture google maps? Can I use print screen?

Comment: The allallsoft stuff- sure looks like it.  Why are you so intent on grabbing google tiles?  Use OpenStreetMaps if you want stuff you can use this way.

Comment: I need higher resolution satellite imagery, than I can save from Google Earth. It saves only in the size of my screen resolution. Does open street map has satellite imagery?

Comment: I think this software is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely cannot write a program to download and save Google tiles.

When IE does that

a) it is the google control instructing IE to do it- IE is not doing that on its own

b) IE is making transient copies for the purpose of display, the intent is clearly not to save them

Comment: sorry to reply to this 4 years later but this statement is incorrect. Maybe at the time of writing this answer it was correct but right now in September 2017 the ToS do allow you to download tiles under certain conditions. These include reasoning along the lines of improving the maps service when network latency is at play and keeping these tiles no longer than 30 days. See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en#section_10_5