# Clipping a section from google map as geotiff

Tags: python, google-maps, google-earth, google-maps-api

I am trying to export regions of interest in google map as geotiff. I know google earth has option to save image as jpeg.

Are there any tools to obtain a part of image from google maps with its world file or as geotiff?

Is there any way to do that with python?

Answer (score 4):

[Google don't like copying or saving](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) of their map/earth products. So I doubt it is possible within their API.

However it is possible to get a georeferenced gtiff of google maps imagery for a limited area through Qgis:

1. Use google street within the Openlayers plugin
2. Zoom to the area you want
3. Go to project -> Save as image and choose tif
4. Open the image, provide the correct projection info (EPSG: 3857)
5. Right click the image in the layers panel -> save as  Gtiff

This is limited to the area within the map canvas, but if imagery for a larger area is needed, it can be repeated several times and the images tiled. But depending on your intended use this may be contravening the google terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

[Downloading images from Google Maps is against the Terms of Service.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69962/download-google-map-tiles-images)

You can, however, embed maps using Google Maps APIs.  See: 
[Google Static Maps Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)

Comment: Ok Let me change my questions then, Is there anyway to export the histogram information of the region of the interest then? I would like to apply histogram similarity measures on images in my collection based on the histogram information I get from the region of interest from google map.

Comment: @ncelik why not consider other free satellite images, is it resolution issue ?